# regression model can't achieve low bias and low variance at the same time

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, mse, bias-variance-tradeoff

I am running a RandomForestRegressor model on a dataset and it seems it can NOT achieve low bias and low variance at the same time. So I suspected that the input (independent) variables are not predictive to the target. I took a closer at the data and found that 95% of the target variable are just zeros. I removed those zeros and then the regression model worked fine - with reasonable variance and reasonable bias. But that's just on the 5% data.

My question here is: in this case, is it possible to properly train a model to include all the data, so that I don't have to get rid of the 95% data? If the answer is yes, how? Because it is also important for me to know if a prediction is zero. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you are using bias,variance appropriately.can you define them.

Comment: The idea behind RF is to have low bias and low variance, through bootstrapping and feature bagging. How did you figure out that your model does not have low bias and variance?

Comment: well I probably have been using the terms in stats and in machine learning interchangeably. My model is either overfitting (excellent performance on train but bad on test ) or not predicting (bad performance on train ... ). This is how I figured. @user2974951

Comment: This will require more information then, since we cannot tell why your model is overfitting or not learning without seeing your data and your models.